# How can I restrict AWS AMI usage by owner in an IAM policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Here is a condensed (but formatted) policy snippet:

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
      "Resource": [ 
         "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::image/ami-*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
         "StringEquals": {
            "ec2:Owner": "987654321000"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
      "Resource": [ 
         "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:000123456789:instance/*",
         "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:000123456789:subnet/*",
         "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:000123456789:volume/*",
         "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:000123456789:network-interface/*",
         "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:000123456789:key-pair/*",
         "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:000123456789:security-group/*"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Assuming **000123456789** is the account where the policy is active. 
Assuming **987654321000** is the account where the AMI is shared from and is the owner.

This policy fails in the policy simulator with I apply the correct condition entries and does not work as expected in the target account -- it fails.

What am I overlooking?

As I read this:

Allow ec2:RunInstances in us-east-1 using any AMI in us-east-1 where the owner is **98765432100** given any instance, subnet, volume, eni, key-pair, or sg located in us-east-1 in the target account **000123456789**.

What is causing this to fail?

Answer (score 1):

Your policy works fine for me. Here's what I did:

- Created a new IAM User and stored their credentials via `aws configure --profile foo`
- Gave that IAM User your policy, but:

  - Changed Regions (I use `ap-southeast-2`)
  - Changed `000123456789` into my Account ID
  - Created an AMI in a *different* account, shared it with the first account, and changed `987654321000` into that Account's ID
- Launched an instance from the AWS CLI:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-xxx --security-group-id sg-xxx --instance-type t2.nano --region ap-southeast-2 --profile xxx
```

It successfully launched the instance. However, specifying an AMI from a different account caused the launch to fail (as desired).

One thing I did notice is that launching with an AWS-supplied AMI requires `ec2:Owner` to be set to `amazon` rather than an Account number.

Comment: Thanks -- I'm not crazy and this does work somewhere. Math is not broken. False does not equal true (outside of politics, anyway). Dogs and cats aren't living together in harmony. There is no mass hysteria.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want [Level 300: IAM Permission Boundaries Delegating Role Creation](https://wellarchitectedlabs.com/Security/300_IAM_Permission_Boundaries_Delegating_Role_Creation/README.html), replacing Role Creation with AMI usage)

Based on using [IAM Permission Boundaries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_boundaries.html)

Comment: Close. Applying a permission boundary is good practice where you want to let your devs stage agile -- assuming you define the PB as the maximum blast radius you're willing to accept. I use those to mitigate risk.

Comment: In this case above though, the logic is failing me somewhere. Assume that the policy above was all there was to it -- there was nothing else. If I ran ec2:RunInstances against that, with the conditions fulfilled, it should result in an "allowed" but it fails -- without much information as to why.